# unparse the intermediate representation of c code back to c

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, llvm

I have a file written in c programming language and is preprocessed using CIL. Now there are calls to a function say foo() in this file. I want to modify the c code in this file such that all calls to foo() are under a #ifdef guard. I want only the calls to be guarded and not the function body so that I have finer control over the calls. The calls can be inside a if condition or a while loop. The rules for macro name: name begins with MACRO_ and ends with the line number of the function call foo() in the original code.

This is to be automated inside a tool and I am looking for a compiler that can unparse c code for doing this.

Example:

**Input source file**

```
void foo(int x){
 // do something
}

int main(){
 int a;
 printf("doing something");
 foo(a);
 printf("doing something again");
 foo(a);
 return 0;
}
```

**Desired output**

```
void foo(int x){
 // do something
}

int main(){
 int a;
 printf("doing something");
#ifdef MACRO_1
 foo(a);
#endif
 printf("doing something again");
#ifdef MACRO_2
 foo(a);
#endif
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Soo...fire up your favourite editor and get cracking. Or is there some sort of logic to the replacements that would allow them to be automatised?

Comment: As your `foo()` has type `int` consider posibilities of calling functions in expressions such `a = b + foo(c);` or `if( foo(y) < MAX || c > 0)`, for which `#ifdef` cannot be directly apply

Comment: @Wintermute - I want to automate this task

Comment: @VolAnd - Thanks for the comment. That was my bad. The specification for my functions does not have a int return type. Sorry for that.

Comment: So what are the rules for which call to `foo` should be guarded by which macro?

Comment: @Wintermute All calls to foo should be guarded. The guard name should begin with MACRO_ and end with a number that number can be the line number the call is on in the original code.

Comment: The calls to `foo` are all on their own line, and no need to worry about stuff like `if(something)\nfoo(bar);`?

Comment: @Wintermute The call can be inside an if.

Comment: Then you'd need to put the `if` inside the macro as well, or you'd have a syntax error (unless it is all inside brackets that are not on the same line as the `foo` call). I'm trying to evaluate if this can be solved on a line-by-line regexy basis, so you could just shove it through awk.

Comment: @Wintermute The calls to foo can be inside a if or even a while. However, these calls to foo are special function calls for probing and I expect that there are other lines of code in such blocks.

Comment: @dvs: please edit your question to improve it, instead of adding explanations in comments

Comment: What is this CIL and how can I search for it without getting only results that talk about language-formerly-known-as-MSIL?

Comment: @Leushenko Here is a link to CIL home page (http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~necula/cil/)

Answer (score 1):

You could customize some free software compiler. If using some recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you could customize it with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (a Lispy domain specific language to extend `gcc` & `g++` etc....).

You probably do not want to produce idiomatic C code. It would be much simpler to customize your compiler (e.g. GCC -or perhaps [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) ...) to have the desired behavior.

Transforming some internal compiler representation (e.g. [Gimple](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) for GCC) is a bit simpler than outputting C code. It may still mean several weeks of work (because C and C++ are quite complex languages, and compilers have quite complex internal representations).

Notice that your question does not consider what is happenning when `foo` is called *inside* some macro (or inside some C++ template expansion, or perhaps even some inlined function). This shows why working on the intermediate representation(s) of your compiler is worthwhile.

BTW, you might perhaps be interested by [coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/), a source to source free software transformer.

You could also in principle use [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) (to compile your C or C++ code to [LLVM](http://llvm.org/)) then [llvm-cbe](https://github.com/draperlaboratory/llvm-cbe) (an experimental LLVM to C backend)

Comment: Thanks for the links to MELT and coccinelle. I want to transform the code back to C as I want to use over-the-shelf analysis tools again on the source.

Answer (score 1):

For SIMPLE source code, you can obviously do this with a simple script and some regexps in your favourite scripting language (perl, php, awk, python, etc). But it does get increasingly difficult if you start deciding to support for example function calls inside if-statements, member function calls, etc [and want to end up with output code that actually compiles to a correct program].

In that case, you need something that can read (and "understand") C or C++ and produce some intermediate form that you can then process and reissue the source code with modifications. It's far from easy to write such code, no matter where you start from. One solution may be to use Clang as a library. It has facilities to rewrite C or C++ code from it's Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) form. This link shows an example of such a rewriter: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/08/basic-source-to-source-transformation-with-clang

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do if you have code like:

```
 if (x) 
    foo();
 bar();
```

Clearly, just inserting #if for the call to `foo();` will cause the call to `bar()` to be called only when `x` is true, which is probably not what you wanted...

Comment: Thanks for the link to source-to-source transformation with clang. Quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is structured in such a way that guarding the lines with `foo` calls can simply be commented out and that more complex expressions such as `bar(), foo(a)` need not be handled, you could use awk like this:

```
awk '/^\s*foo\(/ { print "#ifdef MACRO_" NR; print; print "#endif"; next } 1' filename.c
```

This will

```
/^\s*foo\(/ {                  # handle lines that begin with foo( preceded
                               # optionally by whitespaces specially by:
  print "#ifdef MACRO_" NR     # printing #ifdef MACRO_linenumber before
  print
  print "#endif"               # and #endif after the line.
  next
}
1                              # all other lines are printed unchanged.
```

**Be aware** that this is a dirty, dirty hack that does not attempt to parse the C code properly. There are a number of ways you can break this, among them such things as

```
if(something)
  foo(a);
```

and

```
foo(
  a
);
```

That would come out as

```
if(something)
#ifdef MACRO_foo
  foo(a);
#endif
```

and

```
#ifdef MACRO_foo
foo(
#endif
  a
);
```

respectively. It may work for your particular case, but it is not a general C-code handling tool.

Comment: If I have CIL preprocessed code then the second case and even the first one will not occur - am I correct on this ? In which case I will go ahead with awk even though I was more interested in a C unparser.

Comment: I am not going to go out far enough on a limb to guess if your preprocessed code contains places where this does not work. This will work if your preprocessed code only contains `foo` calls on lines of its own, it will break otherwise. It is a simple hack that may work if `foo` is not used fancily, but its only virtue is that it is simple. There are many cases that it does not cover.

Answer (score 0):

If the task is to exclude calling of `foo(int)` from code when some macro undefined (or defined), maybe the following approach will work better:

```cpp
void foo(int x){
#ifdef MACRO_foo
 // do something
#endif
}

int main(){
 int a;
 printf("doing something");
 foo(a);
 printf("doing something again");
 foo(a);
 return 0;
}
```

So, you can just exclude body of function and leave function calls in the whole program.

Comment: That will not give me control over the calls to the function. I want finer control.

Comment: If you need control each call individually you should clearly explain rules for making macro insertion to your course code.

Comment: I shall just do that in the question and make the rules more clearer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem. If I choose from the already proposed options, the option to search and replacement by means of IDE editing tools seems the most simple and convenient

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking CIL to do things that CIL cannot do.  Since it operates on preprocessed source code, it doesn't represent preprocessor directives, so you can't "put them into CIL representation" to be regenerated.   You might be able to hack the CIL implementation itself to spit out your directives when it encountered your special circumstance, but it is hard to believe that such a hack would be general in any way.

You said you were looking for a "compiler that can unparse c code to do this".  If you insist on "this" as involving specifically CIL, I think you are out of luck; there's only CIL itself to do this.

If you give up on CIL and will consider a different tool, then I think I have an answer, that will do CIL like things, *can* retain preprocessor directives in the representation (and/or allow you to insert them according to custom rules), and can regenerate valid C source code text.

That tool is our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html), a general purpose program transformation engine, and its [C Front End](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html?Home=CTools).  DMS parses C code into ASTs, and unparse them back to valid source code, including retaining comments.
It can be used to do source-to-source transformations using mixtures of procedure calls on its AST manipulation library, and/or *surface-syntax* source-to-source rewrites.

DMS will capture preprocessor directives in that AST (they are just "more syntax!) in most cases without issues; sometimes you need to modify the source code slightly (permanently) to make preprocessor directives palatable. DMS provides symbol tables for C, and control and data flow analysis; these will need some revision to handle preprocessor conditionality.

To match what you are doing with CIL, you can ask DMS to do the preprocessing; now you end up with an AST that is preprocessor free. DMS's existing symbol tables, CF and DF machinery handle this case directly, now.
So you can carry out sophisticated operations on the AST using that additional information, in way different than but equivalent to CIL.  In addition, you can still modify the ASTs to insert preprocessor directives, which seems to be your key problem.

To achieve your specific effect of call-site specific conditionals, you can take advantage of DMS's [surface syntax source-to-source transformation](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSRewriteRules.html) capability.
The following DMS transform does something like what you want:

```
rule wrap_function_call(i: Identifier, a:arguments ):statement -> statement
"  \i(\a); "
 ->
 "  #ifdef \generate_macro_name\(\i\)
      \i(\a);
    #endif
 "
 if want_to_wrap(i);
```

This rule finds any syntax tree corresponding to a function call as a *statement*, and wraps its in a conditional. (You didn't say what you wanted to do if the function call was part of an expression; that case requires a bit more transformation but could also be handled).  A custom helper function *generated_macro_name* manufactures the macro name using the source position information associated with that identifier AST node matched for the function name.   The transformation is conditioned on another custom helper function *want_to_wrap*, that inspects each matched name to determine if it is one that should be wrapped.

When done transforming the code, you call DMS's prettyprinter machinery to print the AST as source text.